# loading media file from css

Tags: magento-1.9, css, url, media

I'm new to magento (using it from only 1 weeks) and I'm trying to use the following instruction from a css file located in

```
skin/frontend/responsive/<storeViewName>/css/<MyDevName>/slideShow/mySlideShow.css
```

which I think is the good place and practice. I'm using the following instruction for which I have an issue:

```
.mySlider {        
    background-image: url(<media_base_url>/arlian/slideShow/loading_icon/ajax-loader.gif) !important;        
}
```

I have stored my loader img also where I think it is the right place to do so (but I may be wrong):

```
media/arlian/slideShow/loading_icon/ajax-loader.gif
```

My issue is how can I reference the correct path to ajax-loader.gif into the css file ?
I know I can use `Mage::getBaseUrl('media')` from a php/phtml file and `{{media url='....'}}` from CMS/static html but despite all my google search, I didn't find any way to reference the media path in Magento style to be used in a css file.

May someone tell me how to do that or what is the good practice to achieve this if my approch is wrong in the magento world ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my knowledge there is no Magento way you can do this.
 `media` folder in Magento is to store media resources like product images, category images, cached images, etc.
 If you want to use your image in a CSS file then it is better approach to put them inside your `skin_image` folder.  e.g. `skin/frontend/responsive/<storeViewName>/images/<MyDevName>/slideShow/loading_icon` folder.
And use this in your CSS file like,

```
.mySlider {        
    background-image: url(../../../images/<MyDevName>/slideShow/loading_icon/ajax-loader.gif) !important;        
}
```